# Django: Fixture already exists?

Tags: python, django

I'm installing Django fixtures for testing and I keep getting an error saying I'm violating a UniqueConstraint.

1. This data came from `python manage.py dumpdata > data.json`. It's working on the database side.
2. It's loaded in to a test via `fixtures=[]`, so there's nothing to violate.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/aaron/Github/foo-server/fooproject/items/fixtures/default_items.json': Could not load invites.InviteCode(pk=01e710b8-05c8-41b3-b9cf-5d059cbe4101): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "invites_invitecode_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(432d2a2e-6c5d-4502-8c99-86c71a6f45d6) already exists.
```

Comment: So, the import is attempting to import the user with `user_id` (uuid) of `432d2a2e-6c5d-4502-8c99-86c71a6f45d6`, as this field is a unique field, it can not be done. Have you tried importing the fixture in a blank database?

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts it's in a test, so the database is definitely already blank because it's a test database

Comment: Is there anything that you're running prior to installing this fixture that adds users? Have you checked the .json dump to see if that UUID exists more than once?

Comment: Please update if you have found the solution